# How to copy private members of a base class in to a derived class's copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

As title suggests, if I have Derived class's copy constructor I need to copy the Base class's members too however I don't have access to the private members. How do I achieve this?

Comment: make it protected, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have below ways to accomplish this:

(1) Create a base copy constructor (not `private`) and invoke that in derived copy constructor.
example:

```
class Base {
  private: int i;
  public: Base(const Base& copy) : i(copy.i) {}
};

class Derived : public Base {
  Derived(const Derived& copy) : Base(copy) {}
};
```

(2) Make the base members to be copied as `protected`; But this is less preferable way, since you are making assignment and not initialization.

(3) The least preferable way is to make `friend class Derived;` inside the body of `class Base`. Use it only if it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: (3) make child friend of parent

Comment: @itwasntpete It's very bad form for a base class to know about classes that derive from it.

Comment: i know, but its possible :D